# New posting after the answer has been accepted.

Tags: discussion

I am new on this forum and I need to know this thing. 
So I posted a question and another user 'X' posted its solution. I tested it and accepted it as an answer later. I realized later that there was a certain formulation in the solution that I didn't understand. So I did my homework and posted it along with the questions that I had from the proposed solution. Can someone tell me whether 'X' will get any notification of my new post. The guy was really helpful and had answered to my comments which I made before accepting the answer.

Comment: The only way the will know of your new post is if they see it. Answers are notified if you comment on their post though.

Comment: Note that if you click on "share" under your new question, you get some text you can paste as a link to the question.